# Keep showing error on Swift 2.2, but can build successfully

Tags: swift, swift2

After I upgraded to Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2.

In the code,

```
func handleInfo(info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {  
    let aps = info["aps"]  
    if let message = aps!["alert"] as? String {  
      .....  
    }  
}
```

it will keep showing error for this line:

```
if let message = aps!["alert"] as? String
```

[image: (Downcast from 'String?!' to 'Sting' only unwraps optionals; did you meant to use '!!'?)]

But if I build and run, it will run successfully without any issue.
However, it pretty annoying that it keep showing up when I coding.

Anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure out how to get rid of those errors.
In Swift 2.2, it applies more strict rule for the data type.

So if there's a value of key in Dictionary is also a Dictionary, we will need to specify the data type of it.

So originally, we have the code:

```
func handleInfo(info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {  
    let aps = info["aps"]  
    if let message = aps!["alert"] as? String {  
        ..... 
    }
}
```

Now in Swift 2.2 it will be:

```
func handleInfo(info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {  
    let aps = info["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let message = aps!["alert"] as? String {  
        ..... 
    }
}
```

Then errors showing in lines will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

```
func handleInfo(info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    guard let aps = info["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
        message = aps["alert"] as? String else {
            return
    }

    // do something with message
}
```

Comment: Not the solution I want, if you simply code like let message = aps["alert"] as! String, it will still showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your build folder and derived data.  If that doesn't work, unwrapping your variables or using optional chaining should suppress the warning

```
if let aps = info["aps"] {
    if let message = aps["alert"] as? String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or

```
guard let message = info["aps"]?["alert"] as? String else {
    return
}
// ...
```